# How can I nest this mysql query using Promise in express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm trying to nest SQL queries using Promise. I want to run the second query based on the result of the first. I currently have something that looks like this

```
const pool = require("../../config/database");
module.exports = {

    seedTypeChecker: (req, res) => {
            pool.query(
                `SELECT id FROM records  
                WHERE type = 'SM1' and member_id 
                NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM cc_see)`
            )
            .then(rows => {
                const promise_list = rows.map(row => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    return pool.query(
                        `UPDATE records set type = ?, see_issue = ? 
                    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM clearer) 
                    AND id = ?`, [
                            'SM1',
                            '1',
                            row.id
                        ]
                    ).then(resolve(console.log("Success!"))).catch(console.log("Database Error!"))

                }))

                Promise.all(promise_list).then(result => {
                    result.status(200).json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: "Query was successful"
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: "Database Error"
                    });
                });
            }).catch(console.log("Error in the first query"));

    }
```

But I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong that isn't making this work

Here's the error message I was getting

```
TypeError: pool.query(...).then is not a function
```

Also, I tried wrapping them all in a promise like this

```
const pool = require("../../config/database");
module.exports = {

    seedTypeChecker: (req, res) => {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.query(
                `SELECT id FROM records  
                WHERE type = 'SM1' and member_id 
                NOT IN (SELECT member_id FROM cc_see)`
            )
        })
        .then(rows => {
            const promise_list = rows.map(row => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                return pool.query(
                     `UPDATE records set type = ?, see_issue = ? 
                WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM clearer) 
                AND id = ?`, [
                        'SM1',
                        '1',
                        row.id
                    ]
                    ).then(resolve(console.log("Success!"))).catch(console.log("Database Error!"))

                }))

                Promise.all(promise_list).then(result => {
                    result.status(200).json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: "Query was successful"
                    });
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({
                        success: 1,
                        message: "Database Error"
                    });
                });
            }).catch(console.log("Error in the first query"));

    }
```

But I get this message

```
Error in the first query
```

which is meant to be thrown if there was an error in the first query

Comment: `result` is not your response object it's an array of responses of all your update queries. `result.status(200)` will throw an error. also, pls add the output/error.

Comment: The issue is that the error I currently have is raised before this. I still have the error even after wrapping everything in a Promise